# Prove that for any nonzero vectors $\bf u$ and $\bf a$ in $\Bbb R^n$, the vector $\bf a$ is orthogonal to ${\bf u} - \mathrm{proj}_{\bf a}{\bf u}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

> Prove that for any nonzero vectors $\bf u$ and $\bf a$ in $\Bbb R^n$, the vector $\bf a$ is orthogonal to ${\bf u} - \mathrm{proj}_{\bf a}{\bf u}$.

I'm not sure how to start proving this. I don't think I've seen any proofs involving projections at all, just the theorems describing what they are... I've been studying my projection notes and graph examples non stop trying to visualize a way to prove it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ denote the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $a,u$ be nonzero elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The projection of $u$ onto $a$ is given by $$\mathrm{proj}_a(u)=\frac{\langle a, u\rangle}{|a|^2}a.$$

By definition, $a$ is orthogonal to $u-\mathrm{proj}_a(u)$ if we have $\langle a,u-\mathrm{proj}_a(u)\rangle=0$. 
We compute this inner product:
\begin{align*}
\langle a,u-\mathrm{proj}_a(u)\rangle&=\langle a, u\rangle -\langle a,\mathrm{proj}_a(u)\rangle\\
                            &=\langle a, u\rangle -\langle a, \frac{\langle a, u\rangle}{|a|^2}a \rangle \\
&=\langle a, u\rangle-\frac{\langle a, u\rangle}{|a|^2}\langle a, a\rangle \\
&=\langle a, u\rangle-\frac{\langle a, u\rangle}{|a|^2}|a|^2\\
&=\langle a, u\rangle-\langle a, u\rangle=0.
\end{align*}
Thus $a$ is orthogonal to $u-\mathrm{proj}_a(u)$, as desired. Here the only thing I have used is the bilinearity of the dot product and the definition of $|\cdot |$.

Comment: I've never seen this standard inner product notation before. thankyou

Comment: @JL This is the standard notation for an inner product in any inner product space, but the dot product notation "$\cdot$" is probably more common for the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I just find that $\cdot$ doesn't illustrate the (bi)linearity properties as well as $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take the dot product of $\vec{a}$ with $\displaystyle\vec{u}-\text{proj}_{\vec{a}}\vec{u}=\vec{u}-\frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{u}}{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}}\vec{a}$$\;\;$ and show that it is zero.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check that $$\langle {\bf a}, {\bf u} - \mathrm{proj}_{\bf a} {\bf u} \rangle = 0. $$

Remember that, by definition, we have: $$\mathrm{proj}_{\bf a}{\bf u} = \frac{\langle {\bf a}, {\bf u} \rangle}{\langle {\bf a},{\bf a}\rangle} {\bf a}.$$

Substitute and use that $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle $ is bilinear. Can you do it?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative definition states:
$$
\text{proj}_V u = \text{argmin}_{v\in V} \| v-u\|^2
$$
Now with the element $x\in v$ written $v = x a, x\in\Bbb R$:
$$
\text{proj}_V u = \text{argmin}_{x\in \Bbb R} \| xa-u\|^2 \times a
$$and the critical points are solution of:
$$
0 = \frac{d}{dx} \| xa-u\|^2  = 2\langle a, xa-u \rangle = 2\langle a, \text{proj}_V u-u \rangle
$$